# How many low-order bits of an RSA modulus can we safely fix to 1?

Tags: rsa, key-generation

It's easy to generate an RSA modulus $n=p\,q$ of $k$ bits with $n\equiv-1\pmod{2^\ell}$, for $\ell$ up to about $k/2$: we can choose $p$ as usual, fix the $\ell$ low-order bits of $q$ to $-p^{-1}\bmod2^\ell$, and choose $q$ with this constraint. This fixes the low-order $\ell$ bits of $n$ to 1, and thus appreciably simplifies Montgomery arithmetic when using the public key.

As an aside, that could be used to halve the storage requirement for $n$.

**Up to what $\ell$ is that safe?**

Some $n$ (in hex) for $k\in\{256,512,1024,2048\}$, $l=k/2$, generated using [this TiO](https://tio.run/##NY5BS8NAEIXv/RXtLaETdFcpQtyLFUVQqHrwMEwg2CFZmGySZcFDkt@@bgO9veF98/G6OrTc1cH@1jGy0ZU67FW5eek9ilH6AeTRqFt9D7I3Apvt1pvpyFasa1BXmRTq5i4n0JUsZWp/WiuMKVzj6/EZs8F81e7cdydvO0ZPeaGAaWcUlSv6ZMM7uya06MyQjebU/7H/6M9YDJDQJKc84Vrm@eIbr@/zvFuVnzjSqkqXCzhpgTcXuGH/Hfxl6eRggHEBdaCFKMb4Dw).

```
f0e32fe555bf8c5027734fcb32b6d51bffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
dec79757c4b1ca15fbe0854a75f38749df4768884c9e9c24af0f09d61a3d1811ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
af8c7235e1938b869a28c310c362444331f19c9b9cc578751a1a8f0859e1ae72916abd7351d82f0ffcb9b84eca441ee37f3646e5890c4ba94f9d6811d4b7f708ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
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
```

Answer (score 2):

The best methods are able to specify 2/3 of the bits of an RSA modulus (see Joye [RSA moduli with predetermined portion: techniques and applications](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.699.9932&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) and it is suggested this could save bandwidth. Although the paper has only recently been published, it has been in pre-print form for since 2008 and no one has suggested any direct attacks (Coppersmith's attack is analysed; SNFS should be considered in the all 1s case, but the leading 1/3 bits random should prevent the existence of a special polynomial of degree greater than 2).

I'd claim the answer $2k/3$ on that basis.

Comment: Had a quick look. They seem to claim half the bits can be fixed, not two thirds. I probably missed something, though.

Comment: I'm ready to follow the paper that there are ways to generate RSA moduli with 2/3 of the bits fixed. When we fix them arbitrarily (e.g. as a hash), I'm convinced it can't harm much, because we are fixing information that's essentially indistinguishable from what an adversary normally gets in factoring (poncho's reasoning). When we fix to 1, that's another story. NFS potentially getting a serious boost for $n$ with too many high bits at 1 is an example that nasty things can happen.

Comment: @fgrieu As I say for SNFS there's only a guaranteed special polynomial for degree 2. For  other degrees there's a heightened chance of a marginally improved polynomial. In general the binary expansion has a roughly $2^{-kd}$ chance of producing a degree $d$ polynomial with coefficients $k$-bits smaller than generic. In your case the chance is roughly $2^{-kd/3}$. If you tell me the modulus size and probability of an improved polynomial that you accept, I can say more about the security effect.

Comment: The danger with too many 1s or 0s would be a [Schirokauer-style NFS variant](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2010-79-269/S0025-5718-09-02198-X/home.html), but with 1/3 of the bits being effectively random that approach doesn't seem very promising.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the similar RSA key generation process:

Select a random odd value $z$ between 1 and $2^\ell - 1$; choose $p$ as usual, fix the lower $\ell$ bits of $q$ to $z p^{-1} \bmod 2^\ell$ and chose $q$ with this constraint.

Now, this generates RSA keys with the same asymptotic [1] distribution as the standard RSA key generation process.

Now, the only difference between this procedure and yours is that you use a fixed $z = 2^\ell -1$, rather than a random one.  However, the attacker can determine the value $z$ used, and so us telling him which $z$ we picked doesn't give him any additional information.

So, the only question is "does a specific value of $z$ yield a weakness?".  I do not know of any factoring method that is applicable to a specific $z$ value.

---

[1]: I say asymptotic, as the demonstration assumes that the lower $\ell$ bits of primes are evenly distributed over odd values; this has been proven to be true asymptopicly (for fixed $\ell$), it is a reasonable (but unproven) assumption for smaller primes.

Comment: What I feared materializes: reputable experts don't want to commit an opinion on that one, even under the disguise of a pseudonym :-)

Comment: @fgrieu: huh?  I thought I did commit an opinion (and I may be tempted to object you calling me "reputable" :-)

Comment: "I do not know of any factoring method that is applicable" is not quite as strong a commitment as in my wildest dreams (where the expert exclaims _I'd bet the farm on that one!_). Come on, you have the highest reputation of us all: 119k, and counting!

Comment: @fgrieu: "there are no known attacks" is about the best statement we can make about any cryptosystem...